# Get element id from input in table JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table

I would like to get ID (from I don't know if it is string or element that I get). My HTML code and Javascript look like this:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('workerTimes');
var emptyArray = new Array(100);

for (var r = 1, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
  var element = table.rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML;
  emptyArray.push(element.id);

  console.log(element);
}
```

```html
<table class="table" id="workerTimes">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Osoba</th>
      <th>Rozpoczął pracę punktualnie</th>
      <th>Zakończył pracę punktualnie</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="50"></td>
      <td>Jan</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="button_positive" onclick="tickClick(50, 0, 0)">✓</button>
        <button type="button" class="button_negative" onclick="tickClick(50, 0, 1)">X</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="button_positive" onclick="tickClick(50, 1, 0)">✓</button>
        <button type="button" class="button_negative" onclick="tickClick(50, 1, 1)">X</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And console log shows

> < input type="checkbox" id="50" >

but I can't get ID of this element and push to array. How to do this?

Comment: element.innerHTML is just text.  You want to use element.children or potentially element.childNodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **element.innerHTML** but that is just text.
You want to use **element.children** or potentially **element.childNodes** in order to work with the result to get the proper id.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('workerTimes');

var emptyArray = new Array(100);

for (var r = 1, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
  var element = table.rows[r].cells[0].children[0];
  emptyArray.push(element.id);

  console.log(element);
  console.log(element.id);
}
```

```html
<table class="table" id="workerTimes">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Osoba</th>
      <th>Rozpoczął pracę punktualnie</th>
      <th>Zakończył pracę punktualnie</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="50"></td>
      <td>Jan</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="button_positive" onclick="tickClick(50, 0, 0)">✓</button>
        <button type="button" class="button_negative" onclick="tickClick(50, 0, 1)">X</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="button_positive" onclick="tickClick(50, 1, 0)">✓</button>
        <button type="button" class="button_negative" onclick="tickClick(50, 1, 1)">X</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that by first column you mean first row also. You can use
getElementByTagName("TH")[0].innerText to get the value inside that element. 
Another function you can use to get elements is getElementByClassName(). You can pass the argument "*" into the latter two functions to get all elements also, then use the index to access the one you are interested in.